# QGIS clipping virtual raster into tiles using grid layer (polygons)

Tags: qgis, clip, tiles

Using QGIS

I want to clip a 100gb VRT raster (UAS) into tiles using a predefined polygon grid (polygon gpkg). I want each tile file to be named by the value contained in the "grid_square" field inside the grid gpkg.

What raster tool should I use for this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to try a solution in `R` ?

```
library(sf)
library(terra)

grid <- st_read(dsn = "polygon_grid.gpkg")
r <- rast("uas.vrt")

lapply(1:nrow(grid), function(tileIndex) {
    tile <- grid[tileIndex,]
    tileID <- tile$grid_square
    cropped <- crop(r, tile)
    cropped_name = paste0(tileID, ".tif")
    writeRaster(cropped, cropped_name)
}
```